# Name of symbol of null set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

What is the name of the symbol we use for empty set?
Difference in notation of phi and void set? I found that symbols that we use for both are different but I know the name phi only. Not know the name of symbol of empty ser

Comment: I've only heard it referred to as the "empty set symbol". You can get it in LaTeX with `\emptyset`.

Comment: In LaTeX, you produce it with the name \emptyset, but as for the typographical name...that's probably not a math question.

Comment: It apparently comes from the [Danish letter Ø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98), as opposed to the Greek $\phi$.

Comment: Which means $phi$ and empty set notation both are different

Comment: we put a slash through 0 to differentiate it from O, which according to MathJax could mean 'not zero'.

Comment: I have only ever seen $\phi$ or $\Phi$ as the empty set in notes and exercises written by people that do not take care of their notation. The symbol you are talking about is $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia André](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Notation) Weil (and maybe others) introduced the symbol $\emptyset$ for the empty set. They were inspired by the [letter Ø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98) in the Norwegian and Danish alphabet. So, I guess you could argue that the symbol should be pronounced as it is pronounced in these alphabets.

In my experience most mathematicians just call the symbol "empty set".

Note also, that the Wikipedia article says that the symbol is not to be confused with the Greek letter $\phi$ or $\Phi$.

Comment: OK in mathematics we call it by empty set not by its Danish language name.

Comment: @user270371: I am not sure that the symbol is supposed to be the Danish (or Norwegian) letter, but it is inspired by it. In short I don't think the symbol has a name. If you insisted on giving a name, maybe the most natural thing would be to call it by the name of the symbol that it was inspired by.

Comment: OK I am going to tell about void set to my friends tomorrow . is it good to tell them this symbol has no natural name. We will call it by empty set only.

Comment: @user270371: My guess here is that the symbol doesn't have a universally accepted name and I think this is safe to tell your friends. But you could also point out that the symbol didn't come out of no where, but it was *inspired* by the Danish symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Although not mathematics, I thought I would add that in the APL programming language the empty vector is represented by the symbol [`⍬`](https://help.dyalog.com/18.0/Content/Language/Symbols/Zilde%20Symbol.htm), which is pronounced "zilde".